# choose midpoint visit for an unbalanced longitudinal data

Tags: r

I have some unbalanced longitudinal data with (number of visits are different for each participant). I want to extract midpoint visit per participant, and convert it to a data frame. So

1. if a participant has a odd number of visits it will be single visit;
2. if a participant has an even number of visits then it will be an average of two visits.

I though I might first use `table()` to count the number of visits by participant `id`, then extract midpoint visit depending on whether it's odd or even.

```
#Here is simulated data:
id <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4),rep(3,15),rep(4,8))
b <- c(rnorm(32,25,1))
c <- c(rnorm(32,30,1.5))

data <- cbind(id,b,c)
count.id <- table(id)
```

It there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an easy way for you. To make it easier for you to check correctness, try this sample dataset:

```
id <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4),rep(3,15),rep(4,8))
b <- c(1:5, 1:4, 1:15, 1:8)
c <- b
data <- cbind(id,b,c)
```

As:

```
> table(id)
id
 1  2  3  4 
 5  4 15  8
```

The correct answer is `3, 2.5, 8, 4.5` for both `b` and `c`.

Now:

```
## a function to return relavant mid points
mid <- function(id) {
  x <- table(id); y <- c(0, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])
  fun <- function(x) switch(x%%2 + 1, c(x/2, x/2+1), (x+1)/2)
  rep(y, 2 - x %% 2) + as.numeric(unlist(tapply(x, 1:length(x), FUN = fun)))
  }

## use na.action = na.pass if you want to retain missing values
## use subset = mid(id), to process the subset involving mid points
## formula methods of aggregate takes data frame
aggregate(. ~ id, as.data.frame(data), FUN = mean, subset = mid(id),
          na.action = na.pass)
```

And you get:

```
  id   b   c
1  1 3.0 3.0
2  2 2.5 2.5
3  3 8.0 8.0
4  4 4.5 4.5
```

Comment: I tried that and the median does not extract the middle visit.

Comment: Also I have some missing values in my data and aggregate function may not work.

Comment: Yes it is fine to have missing value.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is brilliant.